# could not build dsn for snowflake connection: no authentication method provided

Tags: terraform, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, terraform-provider-aws, dsn

I am following this terraforming Snowflake tutorial: https://quickstarts.snowflake.com/guide/terraforming_snowflake/index.html?index=..%2F..index#6

When I run the command `terraform plan` in my project folder, it says:

```
provider.snowflake.account
  Enter a value:
```

and then

```
provider.snowflake.username
  Enter a value: MYUSERNAME
```

Which value do I have to enter? I tried entering my snowflake instance link as the account value:

dc70490.eu-central-1.snowflakecomputing.com

as well as `dc70490`as the account

and then my username MYUSERNAME as the username value.

However, it gives me an error that:

```
│ Error: could not build dsn for snowflake connection: no authentication method provided
│ 
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/chanzuckerberg/snowflake"],
│   on <input-prompt> line 1:
│   (source code not available)
```

I also tried `tf-snow` as the username, since we exported this in a previous step of the tutorial

Answer (score 1):

The account name should be without snowflakecomputing.com and the username need not be in caps.

https://quickstarts.snowflake.com/guide/devops_dcm_terraform_github/index.html?index=..%2F..index#3

Edit:

This is what I have used for terraform configuration to Snowflake for successful connection.

```
    provider "snowflake"{ 
      alias = "sys_admin" 
      role = "SYSADMIN" 
      region = "EU-CENTRAL-1" 
      account = "abcd123" 
      private_key_path = "<path to the key>" 
      username = "tf-snow" 
}
```

Comment: I tried with ```dc71234340490``` as account name and then both ```username```(the one I used to login to interface) as well as ```tf-snow```but I still the same error

Comment: The account name should be dc71234340490.eu-central-1 and the user name should tf-snow.

Comment: Already tried that, but it gives the same error

Comment: Try to add this parameter:

provider.snowflake.authenticator

and then pass the value as snowflake

Comment: Where do I add this parameter? ```provider.snowflake.account``` comes automatically in my terminal when I do ```terraform plan```. It's not something I am adding myself

Comment: From what I see here https://quickstarts.snowflake.com/guide/devops_dcm_terraform_github/index.html?index=..%2F..index#3 , the values are passed as environment variables. Are you able to test this based on the aforementioned link? There add the additional variable SNOWFLAKE_AUTHENTICATOR and set it's value to snowflake.

Comment: Have you got this working successfully?

Comment: Have added the provider data with which the connection could be established successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I've been testing the Snowflake provider with version **0.25.10**.
From 0.25.10 - to - 0.25.11, 0.25.11 was able to see resources the previous version (0.25.10)  couldn't. The current version is 0.26.33.

I'm using Terraform 1.1.2. This is all important, because, along the way I've seen many strange errors depending on the combination.

If in doubt, try 0.25.10 first. I used:

```
provider "snowflake" {
  account  = "zx12345"
  username = "A_SUITABLE_USER"
  region   = "eu-west-1"
  private_key_path = "./my_private_key.p8"
}
```

I created a Snowflake user with key/pair authentication. Look at that private key path (Not for production kids), when I put it in a suitable location:

`~/.ssh/my_private_tf_key.p8`

This was the error:

> Terraform v1.1.2
>
> on linux_amd64
> Configuring remote state backend...
> Initializing Terraform configuration...
>
> Error: could not build dsn
> for snowflake connection: Private Key file could not be read: Could
> not read private key:
>
> open /home/terraform/keys/tf_london_admin_key.p8:
>
> no such file or directory
> with provider["registry.terraform.io/chanzuckerberg/snowflake"],
> on main.tf line 27, in provider "snowflake": 27: provider
>
> snowflake" {

Why highlight this? Because, I have no idea how it decided to use that dir, there's not even a /home/terraform/ dir on my system. Completely made up.
So let's just say, I'm not sure this provider is ready for prime time!
Day wasted, (YMMV).

I hope the Chan/Zukerberg combo keep supporting this going forward; I'll open a few issues on GitHub, I'm sure when all the issues are ironed out it'll be good, as I said, probably not for production though.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in the Snowflake tutorial, the path of the ssh key should not be :

```
export SNOWFLAKE_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH="~/.ssh/snowflake_tf_snow_key"
```

but

```
export SNOWFLAKE_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH="~/.ssh/snowflake_tf_snow_key.p8"
```

Please not that you should run `terraform plan` to make it work and not `sudo terraform plan` otherwise it will look for a ssh-key in `/root/.ssh/` instead of `$HOME/.ssh/` and so the whole process won't work.